# Add double quotes to character

Tags: r

Is there a way to add double quotes to the character

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("A","B"), b = c("C","D"))
paste0(df$a,"=",df$b,collapse = ",")
[1] "A=C,B=D"
```

Can we make if like below

```
[1] " A="C",B="D" "
```

Comment: another one `toString(sprintf('%s=%s', df$a, dQuote(df$b)))`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly are you trying to do, you could use:

```r
> paste0(df$a, '="', df$b, '"', collapse = ",")
[1] "A=\"C\",B=\"D\""
```

Using `cat` for printing the output gives you

```r
> cat(paste0(df$a, '="', df$b,'"', collapse = ","))
A="C",B="D"
```

Answer (score 0):

`glue` may be quite useful:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(str = glue::glue('{a}="{b}"')) %>% 
  pull(str) %>% 
  str_flatten(collapse = ",") %>% 
  cat()
```

Result:

`A="C",B="D"`